# Is it possible to contruct array in Java without number of elements?

Tags: java, arrays, dynamic, static, element

I have some problem when using array in Java. If I declare an array of character like this, my program will throw exception "out of bound array":

```
char[] ipx = {};
for( int i =0; i <= 63 ; i++ ){
ipx[i] = myString.charAt(i);
}
```

I do not know why it is ok when i replace the first line by:

```
char[] ipx = new char[64];
```

I think both of them are correct because i used to delare new string like this:

```
String newString = "";
```

what's the difference between those ? 
Many thanks for any help you may be able to provide

Comment: `{}` is equivalent to `new char[0]`. Basically, an empty array.

Comment: Print `System.out.println(ip.length);`

Comment: You should look at the basic array tutorial on oracle's site: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html. If you don't have a set size for the array you should be using a collection like ArrayList

Comment: Don't agree with the close vote. He has demonstrated an understanding of what an array is, so he's trying to expand on that knowledge. He could have easily researched it on his own, but that's not a reason to close with the minimal understanding reason. If anything, it should be closed as a duplicate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I do not know why it is ok when i replace the first line by:

Because `char[] ipx = {};` is equivalent to `char[] ipx = new char[0]; // zero sized array;`
and in latter case `char[] ipx = new char[64];` you allocate 64 chars for your array.

Answer (score 2):

No, it has to be initialized to a size at some point. In your example, you can just use: myString.toCharArray();

Typically you'd use Lists for things of unknown size and then do myList.toArray();

Answer (score 1):

In a nutshell, you should not attempt to draw any parallels between `String` and `char[]`. They are *very* different creatures in Java.

If you wish to access element `k` of an array, you need to ensure that `k` is a valid index (i.e. that the array is large enough). A zero-length array (`{}`) is not large enough for *any* element access.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to contruct array in Java without number of elements?

In your case, ***yes***, just replace

```
char[] ipx = {};
for( int i =0; i <= 63 ; i++ ){
ipx[i] = myString.charAt(i);
}
```

by

```
char[] ipx = myString.toCharArray();
```

You can also use a `ArrayList<Character>` without declaring the number of elements.

Comment: This is misleading; that will still construct an array of a certain fixed length, this just creates an array of char[myString.length]

Comment: You're right but still the coder doesn't need to specify the length of char array in his code, the method String.toCharArray() will do it for him. I don't think the answer is misleading as I'm starting the explanation with "In your case". Surprisingly, the 'accepted answer' doesnt even answer the question.

Answer (score 0):

If you do `char[] ipx = {}`, it means you create a reference `ipx`. Same as you do `char* ipx` in C++, which is a pointer points to a `random address`. In order to store elements in it, you need to allocate memory like in C++ you need to do `char* ipx = new char[64]`. Therefore, if you only do `char[]ipx = {}` which is equivalent to `char[]ipx = new char[0]` in Java.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, all arrays in java are basic data structures and must have a pre-defined fixed length. Changing the length necessarily requires creating a new array.

If you want to handle collections of objects with variable size, what you want is a Collections Object from the Java libraries, which is more intelligent than a basic data array.

The List class in particular, ArrayList, will perform exactly what you want. It is a List of objects (instead of an array) and will resize itself naturally as you add or remove elements.